# Expected behaviour with Arrow Builder schema change on existing ArrowDB records?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow, arrowdb

I'm in the process of building a custom ArrowDB model through Arrow Builder and have published it using "appc publish" - let's call this schema "v1". I inserted a record into my custom "Customers" table after first publishing it. Later on, I added a new photo_id field to the Customers model - let's call this schema "v2" - and published again, forcing an overwrite of the existing model.

Now, when I try to issue an Update (through the generated API for Customers) to the existing record to add a value for photo_id, I get a 204 response from the call, but the photo_id value is not updated. If I add a new record at this point, I can add and update the photo_id with no problem.

So my question is - is this expected behaviour? If so, how do I update all the v1 records to the new v2 schema?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Since ArrowDB is a MongoDB it should store the value regardless of the schema. Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: On further investigation, it's maybe not exactly a bug, but a lack of error information from Arrow. I shouldn't be allowed to add a photo_id field because it's already a standard field for every ArrowDB model. However Arrow didn't complain and allowed me to do it.

Comment: Well, I'd say that's both a documentation and code bug (it should have warned). Could you raise a ticket?